# Reporting WHICH field caused an error in the pyodbc call to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, exception, try-catch, pyodbc

I have a collection of python files, each of which uses a number of calls of the form:

```
sql_str = "exec SP_UPDATE;"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql_str)
except pyodbc.OperationalError as error:
    print("Connection issue.  connection failure")
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as error:
    # Note this error is specific to a table and a row
    log_error(cursor, __file__, '', 'SP_UPDATE', 0,
              "Failure running update production table for SP_UPDATE"
              "SP_UPDATE" +
              "",
              f'pyodbc error message: {error}')
```

The SP's look similar too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [].[SP_UPDATE]
    @id_something [nvarchar] (500) NULL,
    @d_dt_start [date] NULL,
    @d_dt_end [date] NULL
    ...
AS
BEGIN
   something
END
```

Now the code works - most of the time.  But I'm concerned about when the code does NOT work, which is always due to bad data. This code fragment is called in a loop. I should save the row number. That's helpful. But I would *really* like to know which column caused the problem and report that as well, because the real dataset has anywhere from 7 to over 200 columns.  Is there way to figure that out?

Comment: Perhaps your stored procedure should validate the data and return a more specific error, without seeing more of your code and what error is being generated, cannot advise. `from 7 to over 200 columns` how can it have different numbers of columns? Are you using dynamic SQL to do generic updates as that is not a very good idea? And why would you have 200 columns anyway, sounds like bad design to me. An ID sized to `nvarchar(500)` sounds strange also. You also shouldn't have sproc names starting `sp_` it's reserved for Microsoft.

Comment: @Charlieface There are N tables, 4N stored procedures, and several python programs.
Each table has a fixed number of columns, same with the SP. However, they are all invoked from python in the same way with a try ... except. 

I see what you're saying. That's helpful. Lotta work. I better get busy. tx

Comment: Let's just say if you have a lot of tables with the same schema then something is wrong. Also you shouldn't do anything in SQL in a loop if you can help it, SQL likes sets.